# Oracle Median in Window Function with Range Between

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any workaround that i can use the MEDIAN function within a window for a specific interval range?
I want to use:

```
MEDIAN(numcolumn) OVER (PARTITION BY a
            ORDER BY date_b RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '30' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
            )
```

Oracle throws an error as it is not allowed to use ORDER BY here. The Statement works with AVG.
Is there any fast way i can make this work with window functions and not use something slow as inner joins for huge amount of data?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked many times, but on quick review, I haven't been able to find any with a satisfactory answer. Oracle does not permit the `ORDER BY` clause in `MEDIAN` (though it does with `AVG`!). Many folks have commented that this would be meaningless since `MEDIAN` computes a result from an unordered set and ordering it would accomplish nothing, but this misses the important point that in order to do range windowing (like running averages, running medians, etc..) you need to specify order in order to create the range logic. So not supporting `ORDER BY` means you cannot use `ROWS BETWEEN` like you are trying to do, and that is a gap in Oracle's functionality. Maybe in a future version they'll fix this.

To accomplish what you need I suggest the following:

```
SELECT (SELECT MEDIAN(t2.numcolumn)
          FROM tbl t2
         WHERE t2.a = t1.a
           AND t2.date_b BETWEEN t1.date_b - INTERVAL '30' DAY AND t1.date_b) thirty_day_running_median
  FROM tbl t1
```

Just make sure you have an index on `tbl(a,date_b,numcolumn)`

Comment: Thanks, i feared that this workaround is needed. I'll have to stay with AVG then :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `median` is not exposed as an [analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) with full window syntax support, you cannot use it with window specification clause.

However, such limitations can generally be pushed using [`model`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-modeling-data-warehouses.html#GUID-538F78AA-9BF3-46F2-93D1-39A8739B3237) clause, where you may use (less strict) aggregate functions in the cell calculation.

Steps to emulate `median` analytic function with offsets:

- Put your `partition by` columns in the corresponding clause of `model`.
- Put your `order by` columns into `dimension by` clause. You will be able to specify relative restriction on these columns using current (in terms of currently processing row) value of these dimensions by means of [`cv(dimension_name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CV.html#GUID-32E56E9C-4F59-486E-8E4C-F332284C5EA7) function.
- If you have more than one occurrence of the dimension value you need to adjust the model clause so it will know what it should do:

  - Add `unique single reference` to ignore complains about not unique addressing of cells: we want to process logical intervals (`range between`), not physical.
  - Use `row_number` function with the ordering by required expressions as `dimension by`. It will allow offsetting by this value, which is equivalent of `rows between` (as long as row number is unique per partition).
- Add all the expressions that are not part of `partition by` and `dimension by` as `measures` clause: you don't have to specify rules for them, but it will expose them to the `select` list and right-hand side of the `rules` expression.
- Add some artificial/default value for the newly calculated expression ("analytic function" value) to the `measures`: it will hold the result.

Combining all together, we will use `date_column between cv(date_column) - interval '30' day and CV(date_column)` as reference cells for calculation and `median` as an aggregate function over this range.

The resultant query

```
select *
from sample
model
  /*For model not to comply
    about duplicate dimension value.
    Equivalent of range between.
    For rows between semantics you have to
    add row_number() by the required expressions
    and use it as a dimension value for offsetting*/
  unique single reference
  /*partition_by columns*/
  partition by (id)
  /*order_by column for window*/
  dimension by (dt)
  measures (
    /*other attributes go here*/
    /*an expression to pass as an
      argument for median
    */
    val,
    /*measure for median value*/
    0 as med
  )
  rules update (
    med[any] = 
      median(val)[
        /*window specification*/
        dt between cv(dt) - interval '5' day and cv(dt)
      ]
  )
order by id, dt
```

returns this result for randomly-generated dataset (represented by the first three columns) and **5 day** window:

| ID | DT | VAL | MED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-05-10 | -1 | -1 |
| 0 | 2023-05-12 | 2 | 2 |
| 0 | 2023-05-12 | 3 | 2 |
| 0 | 2023-05-16 | 5 | 3 |
| 0 | 2023-05-17 | -4 | 2.5 |
| 0 | 2023-05-19 | 6 | 5 |
| 0 | 2023-05-24 | -7 | -.5 |
| 0 | 2023-06-01 | 8 | 8 |
| 0 | 2023-06-04 | 9 | 8.5 |
| 1 | 2023-05-26 | 12 | 12 |
| 1 | 2023-05-28 | -16 | -2 |
| 1 | 2023-05-29 | -19 | -16 |
| 1 | 2023-06-02 | -13 | -16 |
| 1 | 2023-06-03 | 18 | -1 |
| 1 | 2023-06-03 | 11 | -1 |
| 1 | 2023-06-04 | 14 | 12.5 |
| 1 | 2023-06-05 | -10 | 11 |
| 1 | 2023-06-10 | 15 | 2.5 |
| 1 | 2023-06-12 | 17 | 16 |
| 2 | 2023-06-04 | 21 | 21 |
| 2 | 2023-06-10 | 26 | 26 |
| 2 | 2023-06-30 | 20 | 20 |
| 2 | 2023-07-01 | 23 | 21.5 |
| 2 | 2023-07-04 | 29 | 23 |
| 2 | 2023-07-06 | -28 | 23 |
| 2 | 2023-07-12 | 24 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-07-12 | -22 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-07-16 | 27 | 24 |
| 2 | 2023-07-18 | -25 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1-p0OEnS)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used the model clause in another use case and it wasn't quite faster than an inner join which means that for much data it doesn't fit my needs. 
Other than that, good solution!